# ionic nvd3 how to have comma separator for thousands on Y axis

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, graph, nvd3.js

Please have a look at my graph generation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/APCcm.jpg

On the Y-axis, I want to have comma separator for thousands.

For example:

100000 should be 100,000 and 80000 should be 80,000

[Here is my code snippet](https://pastebin.com/vde9C0Xr), refer to `$scope.options`

**UPDATE:**

I tried this with tickFormat

```
                  yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'ktoe',
                    axisLabelDistanc: 40,
                    tickFormat: d3.format(',')
                  },
```

but it appears with comma but for 100,000 the 1 disappears like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3ayZ.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the ticks

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    var format = d3.format(",");
    return '£ ' + format(d); // If you want add '£' symbol
});
```

Adjust the chart left `margin : {left: 40}` to be able to see `yAxis` values on the chart

Hope it helps